# Receipt printer(s) cuts right part of content. (Also on test-print on windows)

Tags: printing, windows-10, thermal-printer, epson, receipt

We are experiencing issues with printing to receipt printers. This goes especially for Epson receipt printers (ex : TM T20III), and also experienced with some Star TSP100 (Futureprint).

As you see on the image, the right part of the print is cut, even the test-print is cut on right side (as you see.. it's not centered)..
When paperwidth has been reduced (see second receipt) it still cuts, but leaves lots of space on right-hand side..
You also see that our custom recept (getFood) is not centered, and lacks information on the right side.

[image]

We have fiddled around with paper width, margins and all other settings possible, but it still happens..

Does anyone have any experience with this? is it usually the drivers which mess this up ? or.. is it windows that can be blamed here ?

Comment: Isn't the page setting of the printer driver incorrect? [EPSON Advanced Printer Driver for TM-T20III](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=6693&pcat=3&pid=6146)

Comment: @kunif : we'll try out this driver and see if it makes any changes :) Think we might have tried it already.. dont remember exactly. very "weird" that the recommended driver doesn't behave properly..

Comment: Is the default setting of the printer hardware and the default page setting / paper size setting of the Windows printer driver inconsistent? I think that Windows test page printing is done according to the default settings of the Windows printer driver.

Comment: @kunif : not sure how to actually check that :) Basically installed the correct drivers, printed the testpage directly from "printers" and experiencing the "off by approx 5 millimeters". There is probably a hack to solve this easilly, but just not sure how-to.

Comment: For STAR Micronics printers, there seems to be such materials. [How do I adjust my receipt printer margins on my Windows PC?](https://support.mindbodyonline.com/s/article/203254923-How-do-I-adjust-my-receipt-printer-margins-on-my-Windows-PC?language=en_US) Is there a similar material in EPSON, or can it be done in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a similar issue and resolved it by setting a custom page size of 72mm.

Create a new paper size by going to: Printer Preferences > Layout > Paper Size (User Defined Paper Size). Name the paper size and accept the changes.

Comment: Thanks for going through this :) That's actually just what we did, so i'll accept this as the correct answer since it is...